# Read numpy arrays from file without importing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I have a file with x dimensional vector storing numpy arrays such as

```
0 0 0 2.4 1.2
1.3 1.4 5.6 2.2
```

I tried to read it using numpy as

```
np.array()
```

Is it possible without importing the package numpy?

Comment: so you want to use numpy without importing it? Seems contradictory. Why no import ? Why do you want to use numpy?

Comment: In brief: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Are you trying to read a `.npy` file? You could rewrite/copy out the parser if you want a lightweight way to read them, but if the data is pretty small to begin with, I'd suggest creating JSONs on the other end.

Comment: Or are the numbers you pasted *literally* the format, i.e. numbers in a text file?

Comment: If it is a plain text file you can read it with the `csv` package or simple text file parsing.  The natural python representation of those numbers is a list of 2 lists.

Answer (score 0):

If I write that test to a file:

```
In [13]: cat stack45745158.py
0 0 0 2.4 1.2
1.3 1.4 5.6 2.2
```

Read all the lines, and split them into strings:

```
In [14]: with open('stack45745158.py','r') as f:
    ...:     lines = f.readlines()
    ...:     
In [15]: lines
Out[15]: ['0 0 0 2.4 1.2\n', '1.3 1.4 5.6 2.2\n']
In [16]: alist = []
In [17]: for line in lines:
    ...:     data = line.strip().split()
    ...:     alist.append(data)
    ...:     
In [18]: alist
Out[18]: [['0', '0', '0', '2.4', '1.2'], ['1.3', '1.4', '5.6', '2.2']]
```

Convert the strings to float:

```
In [19]: alist = [[float(i) for i in line] for line in alist]
In [20]: alist
Out[20]: [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.4, 1.2], [1.3, 1.4, 5.6, 2.2]]
```

Since one sublist has 5 numbers, and the other 4, this about as good as it gets.  It can't be made in to a 2d array of floats.